# Jquery, Open div inside its parent limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive image that contains some tickets ,
and I want that the tickets don't accross its container limits when opened
i can't describe well the problem but this is the example
 http://jsfiddle.net/tnYjP/

```
<div class="container">
 <img src=""/>
   <div class="some" style="top:80%;left:80%">
    <span>Title</span>
    <p style="display:none;">Description
        Description
        DescriptionDescription</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

And the jquery script is:

```
    $('.some').hover(function(){
        var description = $(this).find('p');
        description.show('slow');

    }, function(){
        var container = $(this);
        var description = container.find('p'); 

        description.hide("slow");
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to prevent the title thing from hovering over the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (which can easily not be the case), you want to open the description within the giant TEST container. To do this, you need to set the position elements of the item to be based on `bottom` and `right`:

```
.some{
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:10%;
    right:10%;
    background-color: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.6);
}
```

[Here is an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnYjP/3/)

I also took the liberty of moving your inline styles to CSS, and updating your `.hover()` function to be the more effective `.on()`.